# Ionic with Backand social login: profile picture

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, google-plus, backand

I'm developing an application with ionic and Backand and I'm using the sign in with social accounts with the Backand service.
The social login process is OK, but I want to get the ID from Facebook and Google plus in order to get the profile picture.
I was talking with the support of Backand and I know that in Security and Auth there is an action "beforesocialSignUp" and I have not commented the line to get the data:

```
'use strict';
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {
   // get facebook id and put in fuid field that you need to add to your user object
   userInput.fuid = parameters.socialProfile.additionalValues.id;
   // get gender from facebook and put in gender field that you need to add to your user object
   // userInput.gender = parameters.socialProfile.additionalValues.gender;
}
```

And I have created the fuid field in my user object, but, when I make a login with Facebook or Google+ It doesn't save nothing. The login is OK but I can't get the ID data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

The solution was to set the where condition of the BeforeSocialSignUp function from false to true.

This is nowhere in the documentation explained.

It took me 3 day ro figure this out :-(

Now the login works as expected and the fuid field gets assigned.

My next step is to get the profile picture from the FB Account, but therefore I have to make an API request to facebook with a user access token which I dont know how to get from backand.